# XNA - Drawling Linelist (Grid overlay 3d terrain)

Tags: 3d, xna, game-engine

I am trying to overlay a grid on top of my (what will become) a 3d terrain. However right now I am using a list of vertices to draw a linelist. The current line list has 12 vertices and derives this result. I was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction to get the grid working properly?

EDIT: By the way things are working now i would need 30 vertices to get a grid?

Current vertices code:

```
private void SetUpTileVertices()
    {

        tileVertices = new VertexPositionColor[terrainWidth * terrainHeight];
        for (int x = 0; x < terrainWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < terrainHeight; y++)
            {
                tileVertices[x + y * terrainWidth].Position = new Vector3(x, heightData[x, y] + 0.01f, -y);
                tileVertices[x + y * terrainWidth].Color = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

Drawing:

```
device.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.LineList, tileVertices, 0, tileVertices.Length/2);
```

[image: Currently the result]

Comment: A much simpler method would be drawing the terrain with a [Wireframe Rasterizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.rasterizerstate.fillmode(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx). Though I don't know which method would be better performance-wise.

Comment: Like set the rasterizer to wireframe, draw my grid then set it back to fillmode to draw the rest?

Comment: Exactly. You would also want to adjust the depth bias since polygons and lines end up in the same place and would else result in some serious Z-fighting. Or simply switch off depth comparison completely and draw the wireframe *on top*.

Comment: Okay makes sense, How would I not draw the diagonal lines though?

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid, you have to go with the manual approach of creating an additional line list/strip only containing the edges you want visualized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are drawing the terrain... you can calculate the position of terrain pixels in world space, and change its color depending how near is the pixel from the grid lines.

if your vertices are at positions  (0,0), (1,0) , (2,0),....
                                   (0,1), (1,1) , (2,1),....

you can pass the vertex position fron the vertex shader to the pixel shader... and in the pixel shader... you can do something similar to this:

```
  float4 pixel_shader (in float4 color:COLOR0, 
                     in float2 tex: TEXCOORD0, 
                     in float3 pos:TEXCOORD1) : COLOR
  {
     // Don't draw the pixel if it's to close to grid lines, 
     // Instead you could tint pixel with another color .. 
     clip ( frac(pos.X + 0.01) - 0.02 ); 
     clip ( frac(pos.Z + 0.01) - 0.02 );  

     // Sampling texture and returning pixel color code....
   }
```